# Keep stream alive even after onComplete()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

There are two issues which I am currently facing.

1) As soon as the line `RetrofitProvider.getInstance().getCurrentWeather(.....)` is called the network call is being done. How can it be deferred till the observer is connected to it.

2) Once `weatherInfoPublisher.onComplete()` is called, the next time I call onComplete on this object the new observer's onNext is not getting called.

```
public Observable<LinkedList<WeatherInfo>> getWeatherData(final String payload, final TempUnit tempUnit) {

        PublishSubject weatherInfoPublisher = PublishSubject.create();

        RetrofitProvider.getInstance().getCurrentWeather(payload + ",us", translateTempUnit(tempUnit))
            .flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<String> apply(String todayResponse) throws Exception {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Received today weather: " + todayResponse);

                    parseTodayData(todayResponse, weatherDataList);
                    return RetrofitProvider.getInstance().getForecastWeather(
                            payload + ",us", translateTempUnit(tempUnit), FORECAST_DAYS);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(String futureResponse) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Received future weather: " + futureResponse);
                    parseFutureData(futureResponse, weatherDataList);

                    weatherInfoPublisher.onNext(weatherDataList);
                    weatherInfoPublisher.onComplete();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "The error is, " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });

        return weatherInfoPublisher;
    }
```

This is a singleton class and the entire implementation has been provided in here in [Github Link](https://github.com/wwdablu/Weather/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/soumya/wwdablu/weather/dataprovider/OpenWeatherMapProvider.java).

Comment: `How can it be deferred till the observer is connected to it.` Do **not** subscribe to that observable in this method, instead return that observable to the client. As soon as you subscribe - a request would be performed. `the next time I call onComplete on this object the new observer's onNext is not getting called.` See reactive stream specs, if a stream completes - it can never be continued.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I see the issue. The code flow is correct only I missed the proper implementation. Will make the necessary change and update the thread. If works, then would request you to make answer so that I can accept and mark it for others.

Comment: @azizbekian The approach is working good. Can you put the comment as an answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can it be deferred till the observer is connected to it.

Do **not** subscribe to that observable in this method. Instead return that observable to the client. As soon as the observable is subscribed - a request would be performed.

> the next time I call `onComplete` on this object the new observer's `onNext` is not getting called.

See [reactive stream specs](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm): if a stream completes - it can never be continued, that's a terminal event.